# Dynamic X Loopup using Tables - How to tell xlookup which table to use?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup

Currently the formula in cell B3 works by only looking up the value in B2 in the "Total Debt/Capital" table of cells D1:K6. How do I make the formula in B3 dynamic so it will change which table it looks at based in the value in A2 ? So if A2 says "Net Debt / EBITDA" then it will use the table in V1:AC6 to return the value. The correct value returned should be "B".

Current Formula:

```
=XLOOKUP(B2,XLOOKUP(B1,D2:D6,E2:K6),E1:K1,,1,-1)
```

[image: Test File]

Comment: Try: `=LET(
     _LookUpTable, IFS(A2="Total Debt / Capital", Capital, A2="Total Debt / EBITDA", EBITDA, A2="Net Debt / EBITDA", NEBITDA,TRUE, ""),
     XLOOKUP(B2,XLOOKUP(B1,TAKE(_LookUpTable,,1),DROP(_LookUpTable,,1)),E1:K1,,1,-1))`

Comment: You current formula seems strange (the inner XLOOKUP produces a value, which you then use as a range for the outer one). However, in general: you can use a `SWITCH` formula inside `XLOOKUP`, like this `=XLOOKUP(<value>, SWITCH(<selector>,"text1",<table1column1>,"text2",<table2column1>,"text3",<table3column1>),SWITCH(<selector>,"text1",<table1column2>,"text2",<table2column2>,"text3",<table3column2>))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya your formula creates a #Name? error

Comment: Are you using `MS365` and also have you tried to define name as mentioned in answers, it works on my end. Posted in answers 10 mins back using `SWITCH()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

```
=LET(
     _LookUpTable, SWITCH(A2,"Total Debt / Capital", Capital,
                             "Total Debt / EBITDA", EBITDA,
                             "Net Debt / EBITDA", NEBITDA, ""),
     XLOOKUP(B2,XLOOKUP(B1,TAKE(_LookUpTable,,1),
     DROP(_LookUpTable,,1)),E1:K1,,1,-1))
```

---

[image]

---

- Firstly, you need to define the tables accordingly, so for this example I have named the first table as `Capital` --> Range from `D1:K6` , `EBITDA` for `M1:T6` and lastly, `NEBITDA` for `V1:AC6`
- Then apply the above formula using `LET()` function to define variables.
- Using `IFS()` or `SWITCH()` you can return the `_LookupTable` and use as a reference array for the `XLOOKUP()` functions.
- Note that, I have not used anything for the header, because the header is constant across three. but you can make it dynamic as well.

---

Or, making it more clearer, with each steps:

```
=LET(
     _LookUpTable, SWITCH(A2,"Total Debt / Capital", Capital,
                             "Total Debt / EBITDA", EBITDA,
                             "Net Debt / EBITDA", NEBITDA, ""),
     _LookUpArrayO, TAKE(_LookUpTable,-(ROWS(_LookUpTable)-1),1),
     _LookUpArrayT, DROP(_LookUpTable,1,1),
     _Header, DROP(TAKE(_LookUpTable,1),,1),
     XLOOKUP(B2,XLOOKUP(B1,_LookUpArrayO,_LookUpArrayT),_Header,,1,-1))
```

---

**Note:** It can be made more shorter by using `Volatile` functions like `INDIRECT()` but avoided using it since its volatile in nature, will slow down the working functionality of `Excel` as well as it will keep recalculating whenever there is a change in any open workbook.

---